# BottomNavigation is overlapping FrameLayout content in DrawerLayout

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout, android-xml

Every bottom content in FrameLayout is getting hide behind bottomNavigation,
below is my code.....I am making an little complex app where it has both drawer layout and bottomnavigation and I am also using framelayout to show different fragment when menu item is click from bottom navigation ,  the problem is whether i used constraintLayout or linear layout (not as rootlayout)instead of RelativeLayout above both FrameLayout and bottomNavigation its still hide my all fragments bottom content whether its recyclerview or button

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawerLayoutID"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">




<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />




    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_ID"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_navigation_color"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:id="@+id/checkCon"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/navyBlue">



        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/favoriteColor">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/search_editText_id"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_backgrond"
                android:hint="@string/search"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/all_button_id"
                android:layout_below="@id/search_editText_id"
                android:textColor="@color/whiteColor"
                android:text="@string/selectAll"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/search_RecylerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/all_button_id" />

        </RelativeLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: What is the problem in visual form. Like a picture of the problem. Because when I implement your code with constraint layout it works fine.

Comment: I am not a fan of Relative layout I always use constraint layout on all my apps that are on Play Store. But as I said when I use all constraint layouts it works fine with nothing hid.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to provide the bottom constraint of your frame layout to top of the bottom navigation so your frame layout's bottom content will not be hidden behind the bottom navigation.

Refer to this code will resolve your challenge.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawerLayoutID"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<!--    i just changed here to constraint layout from the relative layout.-->
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_setting_background">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_navigation_ID"
        android:background="@color/black"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_ID"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_navigation_color"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation"
  app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/checkCon"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/navyBlue">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/favoriteColor">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/search_editText_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_backgrond"
            android:hint="@string/search"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/all_button_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/search_editText_id"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:text="@string/selectAll"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/whiteColor" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/search_RecylerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/all_button_id" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```